# Windowsのバッチファイルで、指定した時刻に処理を開始し、数秒ごとに同じ処理を繰り返す方法

Tags: windows, batch-file, iperf

Windowsのバッチファイルで、指定した時刻に処理を開始し、数秒ごとに同じ処理を繰り返す方法を教えてください。

ここではiperfを使っており、下記のようなスクリプトを考えました。
本当は00秒になったら起動するようにしたいですが、方法がわかりませんので15時に
なったら起動するように書いています

自動起動スクリプト

```
pause
pause
cd c:\aaa
at 15:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su c:\aaa\iperf.bat
pause
```

数秒毎に同じ処理を繰り返すスクリプトiperf.bat

```
:top
timeout 5
iperf -c 10.0.0.3  -t 5

goto top
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「指定した時刻に処理を開始」であれば、Windowsの「タスクスケジューラ」を使えるのではないかと思います。
Windows7であれば、「コントロールパネル」⇒「管理ツール」⇒「タスクスケジューラ」にありますよ（管理者権限が必要です）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速、その方法も試してみます。